# path detection not working for react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

My code is this but when I go to localhost/fr ,it is not detecting the language from the path? what am i doing wrong here?

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import HttpApi from "i18next-http-backend";

i18n
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    supportedLngs: ["en", "fr"],
    // lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    detection: {
      order: ["path", "querystring", "cookie"],
      lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
      lookupQuerystring: "lng",
      caches: ["cookie"],
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/assets/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json",
    },
    // react: { useSuspense: false },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: there’s a test for it… it seems to work: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector/blob/ff29d32f4f7a6fcca43607e2ff3dab8ff9cf9b8c/test/languageDetector.test.js#L31

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [`next-i18next`](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) as it's geared toward Next.js integration.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use URL in the following way
localhost?lng=fr

From LanguageDetector Package [documentation](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector)

> This is a i18next language detection plugin use to detect user language in the browser with support for:
>
> 1. cookie (set cookie i18next=LANGUAGE) sessionStorage (set key
> 2. i18nextLng=LANGUAGE) localStorage (set key i18nextLng=LANGUAGE)
> 3. navigator (set browser language) querystring (append ?lng=LANGUAGE to
>    URL) htmlTag (add html language tag <html lang="LANGUAGE" ...) path
> 4. (http://my.site.com/LANGUAGE/...) subdomain
> 5. (http://LANGUAGE.site.com/...)

I tried using localhost:3000?lng=fr and that was working for me. let me know if that works for you. localhost:3000 is the URL on which create react app is running on.

Comment: URL in the following way localhost?lng=fr
This works for me.This is using querystring but i want to use path...I want to load load the language using localhost/fr